# Groovy : Getting subLists from a List, based on a field value

Tags: groovy

How should I group a list of user objects, based on their type. For example, i have a list as below.

```
List userList = [userA, userB, userC, userD, userE, userF, userH]
```

And i would like to convert this list into a list.

```
List userList = [ [userA, userB], [userC, userD, userE, userF], [userH] ]
```

Grouped based on the **type** field of user.

Comment: Create a map from the given list where the key would be the type and value would be list of users. finally call map.toList method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `groupyBy()` method:

```
Map map = users.groupBy { it.type }
```

This returns a map of user objects grouped by type.
The map content looks like this:

```
[
  typeA : [list of users of typeA], 
  typeB : [list of users of typeB], 
  ..
]
```

This map can be easily transformed to a list like you need using the collect method:

```
List l = m.collect { key, value -> value }
```

Now `l` is a list that looks like this:

```
[ [list of users of typeA], [list of users of typeB], .. ]
```

All in one line:

```
def list = users.groupBy { it.type } .collect { k, v -> v }
```

Comment: you can also use spread on the groupBy result instead of the collect `users.groupBy{it.value}*.value`

Answer (score 2):

The groovy goodness and only **one line of code**:-)

```
def usersByType = users.groupBy({ it.type }).values().toList()
```